# How to renormalize an image to default values?

Tags: image, tensorflow, matplotlib, artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network

I've used this function for normalization pictures in dataset:

```
tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
```

When my model is trained, i want to plot generated picture, but i don't know how

i tried something like:

```
   generated_image = generated_image*255
```

or

```
   plt.imshow(generated_image[:,:, 0] * 255)
```

But nothing worked(every time i get picture in strange colors) and sometimes i had a couple of warnings from matplotlib (clipping input data to the valid range...)
What should i do?